# bug in storyboard xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard

I lost all my status bar of viewcontrollers and all my item on the storyboard are small.

all my viewcontrollers,navigation controller are flattened.
Can i reset all things in the storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

If the items are small then try enlarging them. For the status bar go to your attributes inspector and in the simulated metrics change status bar to black or translucent black. Or you can check your plist because you may have Status bar is initially hidden to yes